# Can't call specific value in Array that was created by JSON being .push(ed) to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

For some reason I am struggling to figure out how to call specific values that were .push(ed) to an array from JSON.

I have .push(key + ":" value); pushing to an array called tooltipValues.

When I do tooltipValues.join, I can see that everything is populating in my array BUT, the array looks like this in console: `["value1:skill-one value1", "value2:skill-one value2", "value3:skill-one value3"]` , which isn't creating the same model as my JSON.  I want to be able to call tooltipValues.value1 for instance, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I've tried everything I can think of.

Is there a way that I can keep the JSON intact to where I can call each individual value as I see fit? The reason I have this setup this way is to be able to look at my data-tooltip tag in my HTML, compare it to the JSON and pull the JSON that matches the data-tooltip.

You will see below in my JS what I'm doing and commented out, what I would like to do like so:

```
var tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip'>" + tooltipValues.join("<br>") + "</div>")
    // WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO 
    // var tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip'>" + tooltipValues.value1 + "</div><div>" + tooltipValues.value2 + "</div>)
```

Here is my code:

```js
tooltipData = {
  "skill-one": {
    "value1": "skill-one value1",
    "value2": "skill-one value2",
    "value3": "skill-one value3"
  },
  "trinket-two": {
    "value1": "trinket-two value1",
    "value2": "trinket-two value2",
    "value3": "trinket-two value3"
  },
}

$('.skill, .trinket, .hero').hover(
  function() {
    //console.log( 'hovering on' , $(this).attr('tooltip') ); 
    var tooltipJSON = tooltipData[$(this).data("tooltip")];
    var tooltipValues = [];
    
    if (tooltipJSON) {
      $.each(tooltipJSON, function(key, value) {
        tooltipValues.push(key + ":" + value);
        console.log(tooltipValues);
      });
    }
    var tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip'>" + tooltipValues.join("<br>") + "</div>")
    // WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO 
    // var tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip'>" + tooltipValues.value1 + "</div><div>" + tooltipValues.value2 + "</div>)
      .css({
        'color': '#fff',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'zIndex': '99999',
        'width': '100px',
        'height': '150px',
        'background-color': '#333',
      });
    $(this).append(tooltip);
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
      $('.tooltip').css({
        left: e.pageX + 10,
        top: e.pageY - 10
      });
    });
  },
  function() {
    $('.tooltip').remove();
  }
);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='skill' data-tooltip="skill-one">Skill One</div>
<div class='trinket' data-tooltip="trinket-two">Trinket Two</div>
<div class='hero' data-tooltip="hero-three">Hero Vestal</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing some intermediate step, you already have the object as you want it. The defined tooltipData contains objects and when you get it with `var tooltipJSON = tooltipData[$(this).data("tooltip")];`, you get the object in the format you want to use (it is not JSON, it is an JS object)

In other words, you can just use `tooltipValues = tooltipData[$(this).data("tooltip")]` and use it as in your commented out example

```js
tooltipData = {
  "skill-one": {
    "value1": "skill-one value1",
    "value2": "skill-one value2",
    "value3": "skill-one value3"
  },
  "trinket-two": {
    "value1": "trinket-two value1",
    "value2": "trinket-two value2",
    "value3": "trinket-two value3"
  },
}

$('.skill, .trinket, .hero').hover(
  function() {
    //console.log( 'hovering on' , $(this).attr('tooltip') ); 
    var tooltipValues= tooltipData[$(this).data("tooltip")];    

    if(!tooltipValues)return;
    var tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip'><div>" + tooltipValues.value1 + "</div><div>" + tooltipValues.value2 + "</div></div>")
      .css({
        'color': '#fff',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'zIndex': '99999',
        'width': '100px',
        'height': '150px',
        'background-color': '#333',
      });
    $(this).append(tooltip);
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
      $('.tooltip').css({
        left: e.pageX + 10,
        top: e.pageY - 10
      });
    });
  },
  function() {
    $('.tooltip').remove();
  }
);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='skill' data-tooltip="skill-one">Skill One</div>
<div class='trinket' data-tooltip="trinket-two">Trinket Two</div>
<div class='hero' data-tooltip="hero-three">Hero Vestal</div>
```

Comment: You got it! Thanks man. I'm sure I would have figured that out..... eventually haha. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to use a JavaScript Object instead of an Array. An array uses indexes to access elements while an object uses a key value pair which is what you are trying to accomplish. Instead of `.push(key + ":" value)` you should say this:

```
var tooltipValues = {}; //Initialize as an object instead of an array

// ... later on

tooltipValues[key] = value;
```

This will allow you to access your value by using the expression `tooltipValues.key`

It's been pointed out below that although this answer is technically correct, there's no need to do this as you already have the object in the form you need it.

Comment: The tooltipJSON variable is already an object - why create a new one?

Comment: Yeah definitely accurate. That'll teach me to answer the question without reading the code snippet from OP first.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an array of strings in the `tooltipValues` variable. You can achieve the result you want by making those strings the values you need and then just passing them into the DOM elements when the tool tip pops up.

```js
tooltipData = {
  "skill-one": {
    "value1": "skill-one value1",
    "value2": "skill-one value2"
  },
  "trinket-two": {
    "value1": "trinket-two value1",
    "value2": "trinket-two value2",
    "value3": "trinket-two value3"
  },
}

$('.skill, .trinket, .hero').hover(
    function() {
      var tooltipJSON = tooltipData[$(this).data("tooltip")];
      var tooltipValues = [];

      if (tooltipJSON) {
        $.each(tooltipJSON, function(key, value) {
          tooltipValues.push(value);
        });
      }

      var tooltip = $("<div class='tooltip'>");
      for (var i = 0; i < tooltipValues.length; i++) {
        var tip = $("<span class='tip'>" + tooltipValues[i] + "</span>");
      tooltip.append(tip);
    }

    $(this).append(tooltip); $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
      $('.tooltip').css({
        left: e.pageX + 10,
        top: e.pageY - 10
      });
    });
  },
  function() {
    $('.tooltip').remove();
  }
);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.tooltip {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.tip {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='skill' data-tooltip="skill-one">Skill One</div>
<div class='trinket' data-tooltip="trinket-two">Trinket Two</div>
<div class='hero' data-tooltip="hero-three">Hero Vestal</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the way you pushing values:

```
$.each(tooltipJSON, function(key, value) {
    tooltipValues.push(value);
});
```

See working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qcbr4gfg/1/